Как оптимизировать алгоритм ограничения fps в программе, использующей glfw для рендеринга окна?
Всем привет.
Я создаю программу с графическим интерфейсом, в рендере главного окна которой будет помогать glfw.
Сейчас мне нужно разработать участок кода, который будет задерживать выполнение потока в соответствии с fps. Я уже создал три реализации, но ни одна из них меня не устраивает:
 
//объявлены в области видимости старше:
//bool vsync = false;
//unsigned int fps = 60;
//float max_frame_duration = 1.0f / (float)fps;
//float delta_time = 0.0f;
//float last_frame = 0.0f;

float current_frame = (float)glfwGetTime();
delta_time = current_frame - last_frame;

//#1 Задержка реализована многократным выполнением цикла. Грузит ЦП. Погрешность < 1 миллисекунды
if (!vsync)
{
    while (delta_time < max_frame_duration) 
    {
        current_frame = (float)glfwGetTime();
        delta_time = current_frame - last_frame;
    }
}

//#2 Задержка реализована функцией из windows.h. Погрешность 3-11 миллисекунд. Критично для большого fps
if (!vsync)
{
    if (delta_time < max_frame_duration) 
    {
        Sleep((max_frame_duration - delta_time) * 1000);
        current_frame = (float)glfwGetTime();
        delta_time = current_frame - last_frame;
    }
}

//#3 Задержка реализована функцией из thread. Погрешность 3-12 миллисекунд. Критично для большого fps
if (!vsync)
{
    if (delta_time < max_frame_duration)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(long long((max_frame_duration - delta_time) * 1000)));
        current_frame = (float)glfwGetTime();
        delta_time = current_frame - last_frame;
    }
}

last_frame = current_frame;

Как мне сделать эту часть программы наиболее эффективной (С погрешностью не более миллисекунды и не загружающей ЦП)?
Код немного изменён, для краткости. Но, если есть необходимость, вот ссылка на полный вариант файла с ним: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yXazuY0fCI3buxBt5VxxpYZ1jE4fwv2W?usp=sharing
P.S. Впервые задаю вопрос в каком-то сообществе. Если что, поправьте.

¿Эм, а зачем задерживать выполнение потока в соответствии с fps? buffer swap же и так задержит. ¿Возможно это вопрос про обеспечение обновления игрового состояния через фиксированные промежутки (fixed update)?

@user7860670 Видимо, я не совсем ясно выразился. Этими задержками, я хочу ограничить частоту обновления программы в секунду, до желаемого максимального значения (fps). И да, в итоге должны получиться обновления состояния через фиксированные промежутки времени. Я понимаю то, как вычислить время задержки. Основная моя проблема в том, что я не могу найти способ правильно её осуществить.

Это сомнительная затея, обычно стараются, чтобы частота обновления была фиксирована и никак не зависела от fps.

Считаю считать код дельта без учёта времени выполнения отрисовки совершенно неточночным способом, поэтому все твои тесты и провалились.
В любом случае нету такой прям магической функции которая бы считала идеально.
Единственное что могу посоветывать это.

Запомнить perf counter... NtQueryPerformanceCounter
Выполнить код фрейма (отрисовка и.т.д.)
Выполнить повторно NtQueryPerformanceCounter
Расчитать оставшееся время задержки след фрейма
Создать задержку через NtDelayExecution

Это всё функии ядра ОС и они будут давать максимально близкий, но не идеальный результат.
Ps: Полезная информация

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7827101/7316806

Pss: Использование функций ядра и идеальной точности не всегда помогают играм. Люди любят старые игры и если думать в первую очередь не о супрер-точности, а об общей работоспособности возможно твоя игра будет работать на Windows XX спустя 10-15 лет. Для примера Lines98 она как работала на 98 так-же работает и на 10 и на 11, чему я очень рад.

Время выполнения отрисовки и логики высчитывается разницей текущего времени (curren_frame) и времени с начала отрисовки текущего кадра (last_frame). Также, в случае необходимости задержки, к дельте прибавляется и она. Спасибо за ответ!
